# about Clamped cubic spline code in Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, cubic-spline, polynomial-approximations

I did the program, but for some reason it marks a mistake (`c = tridiagonal ( hi(1:n-1), dd, hi(1:n-1), ri );` ) and I don't know why, I'm sure it's correct so please somebody help.
Here is the code:

```
function csc = cubic_clamped ( xi, fi, fpa, fpb )n = length ( xi );        
m = length ( fi );        
if ( n ~= m )
   disp ( 'number of ordinates and number of function values must be equal' )          
   return         
end        
for i = 1 : n-1         
    hi(i) = xi(i+1) - xi(i);         
end          
dd(1) = 2.0*hi(1);  dd(n) = 2.0*hi(n-1);                  
ri(1) = (3.0/hi(1))*(fi(2)-fi(1)) - 3.0 * fpa;        
ri(n) = 3.0 * fpb - (3.0/hi(n-1))*(fi(n)-fi(n-1));        
for i = 1 : n-2        
    dd(i+1) = 2.0 * ( hi(i) + hi(i+1) );        
    ri(i+1) = (3.0/hi(i+1))*(fi(i+2)-fi(i+1))-(3.0/hi(i))*(fi(i+1)-fi(i));        
end          
disp ( [dd' ri'] )        
c = tridiagonal ( hi(1:n-1), dd, hi(1:n-1), ri );          
d = zeros ( n,1 );        
b = d;          
for i = 1 : n-1        
    d(i) = (c(i+1)-c(i))/(3.0*hi(i));        
    b(i) = (fi(i+1)-fi(i))/hi(i) - hi(i)*(c(i+1)+2.0*c(i))/3.0;        
end          
if ( nargout == 0 )        
   disp ( [ xi' fi' b c' d ] )        
else        
   csc = [ xi' fi' b c' d ];        
end
```

tridiagonal code (error is: w = a(i) - b(i)*v(i-1); )

```
function y = tridiagonal( a, b, c, f )            
n = length(f);        
v = zeros(n,1);        
y = v;        
w = a(1);        
y(1) = f(1)/w;        
for i=2:n        
    v(i-1) = c(i-1)/w;        
    w = a(i) - b(i)*v(i-1);        
    y(i) = ( f(i) - b(i)*y(i-1) )/w;        
end        
for j=n-1:-1:1        
   y(j) = y(j) - v(j)*y(j+1);        
end
```

Comment: What is the error? What are the values of those variables when `tridiagonal` is called?

Comment: i don't know, because it marks another mistake in 'tridiagonal' code

Comment: When you say it "marks a mistake", what exactly is the message? If you use the debugger and put a break point at the `tridiagonal` line, you can see what the variable values are just before the function is called.

Comment: it just says: "Error in (line 25) " which is: w = a(i) - b(i)*v(i-1);

Comment: where is the 'debugger'?

Comment: The debugger is in the editor: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html. Are you sure that's all the error says? It should tell you what is actually wrong in line 25.

Comment: yes i'm sure. that's all it says